# Another getLoginStatus not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

First of all, I know there are many similar questions and I've checked all I could find, but nothing seems to work. That being said, here is the minimal setup for the problem:

```
<body>
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
        status: true,
        version: 'v2.1'
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus( function( response ) {
        console.log( 1 );
    }, true );

    FB.Event.subscribe( 'auth.statusChange', function( response ) {
        console.log( 2 );
    });
}
</script>
<button onclick="FB.login();">Login with Facebook</button>
```

All I want is that when the page loads, the console outputs either 1 or 2. But nothing happens. The getLoginStatus callback function is not being called, and the auth.statusChange event is not being fired. However, when I click the login button the 'auth.statusChange' event fires and the console outputs 2, as expected. But when I reload the page, I'm back at the beginning: no output at all in the console.

As you can see, I've included the second parameter of the getLoginStatus to force the roundtrip to Facebook. I've also triple checked my app settings: it's not in sandbox mode and all the domains are ok.   I've copy-pasted the default code provided by Facebook for implementing the login mechanism, but the problem remains. I'm working on the latest Chrome, so it's not IE-related as it seems to be for many of the other questions.

The best clue I have right now is an error that the console outputs three times for every page load:

GET http://static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter/QjK2hWv6uak.js?version=41 408 (Request Time-out)

I've googled the error but found nothing. Anyone knows what it might mean? Or how to make the login work? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my app was using http instead of https. Apparently using https is required in order to use the Facebook login! I changed everything to https and the console outputted both 1 and 2, and the 408 error was gone too.